# Splitting a list of number into N even subsections

Tags: python, list, split

I have a list of numbers, and I want to split them up into N evenly spaced numbers,  while the first and last number must be in the resulting list, all numbers should be an integer, so I'm ok with the space between the last two being off by a little.

For example I have a range of 1-100 and the I want the resulting list in three numbers, so it would be `[1, 50, 100]`. Is there a python way to split them? Or what could be an equation to get the increment? Getting the increment by (last-first)/N will not work because it will results in more numbers.

I couldn't come up with a working equation to get the increment, the best I have is `(last-first-2)/N-2`, but that fails to give an even split on some combinations.

Comment: Did you try (last - first)/(n - 1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `numpy.linspace()`:

```
import numpy as np
np.linspace(1, 100, 3, dtype=int)
```

Output:

```
array([  1,  50, 100])
```

Or if you already had an list of integers, and you wanted to sample from it using this method:

```
nums = range(1,200,2)  # odd numbers 
[nums[i-1] for i in np.linspace(1, 100, 3, dtype=int)]
```

Output:

```
[1, 99, 199]
```